# How can I tell Stardog to use inference when querying it through SPARQLwrapper?

Tags: python, sparql, stardog, sparqlwrapper

I have a SPARQL query that returns results in the Stardog query panel when inference is enabled, but not when it's disabled. When I try the query through python with SPARQLwrapper, I get no results. I tried with a different query, which doesn't rely on inference, and got the same results through the Stardog query panel without inference and through SPARQLwrapper. So I suspect reasoning is not being applied when I query through python, and that this is why there's no results. So my question is *How can I tell Stardog to use inference when querying it through SPARQLwrapper?*

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.stardog.com/#_using_reasoning) of Stardog is pretty good:

> ### HTTP
>
> For HTTP, the reasoning flag is specified with the other HTTP
> request parameters:
>
> `$ curl -u admin:admin -X GET "http://localhost:5822/myDB/query?reasoning=true&query=..."`

which means simply add the param `?reasoning=true` to the remote URL string.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. The solution is to use [`addParameter`](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/doc/latest/SPARQLWrapper.Wrapper.SPARQLWrapper-class.html#addParameter) when you build the query which adds the [required reasoning=true](https://www.stardog.com/docs/#_using_reasoning) to the URL.

A skeleton of a query could then look like this:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

endpoint = '<your endpoint>'

sparql = SPARQLWrapper(endpoint)

# add your username and password if required
sparql.setCredentials('<your username>', '<your password>')

rq = """

<your query string>

"""

sparql.setQuery(rq)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

# use reasoning
sparql.addParameter('reasoning', 'true')

data_json = sparql.query().convert()
```